# C++ How to read and write long numbers (longer than 8 byte) using Oracle in Windows

Tags: windows, oracle

**General explanation**
I need to enhance an existing Oracle OleDB interface written in C++ for a software running on Windows only. The goal is to read and write long NUMBER values (up to 28 digits) without loss of data like it happens when using float/real/double.
The Oracle version this needs to work with is 11.2g or higher.

**The problem**
I am not quite sure what data type I should use for OCIDefineByPos. According to the Oracle documentation SQLT_NUM and SQLT_VNU should be fine. It seems SQLT_VNU is better suited because it exactly matches OCINumber type in data length. But I did try both with the same bad result.
The value returned in the data parameter of OCIDefineByPos is an OCINumber, data length 22 bytes. There are no errors on binding or fetching.

There are two problems with this:
First, what do I do with OCINumber? It is not just a byte array containing the value like a 22 or 21 byte long integer. (I'd like that though)
I know I can convert OCINumber with the [OCINumber functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci19map003.htm#LNOCI185) to integer or double values, but of course that doesn't make sense in my case.
The second problem is that if I use OCINumberToInt, the result for all values is 1. Some of the columns I tried with are short, like NUMBER[1,0] or NUMBER[10,5]. The first column actually contains the value 1, but all the others don't. NUMBER[10,5] contains the value 12345.09876 but I still get 1 as value. (There is only one record in the test table)

I have found information on how to set precision and scale for a column with OCIAttrSet. I thought that maybe this is the root of the problem. I have no information on how to do this correctly though because all examples are detached from the rest of the code. Whatever I try to set OCI_ATTR_PRECISION with OCIAttrSet, I get ORA-24316: invalid handle as result.

**The goal**
is to put the number into the Windows type DECIMAL which can hold numbers up to 12 bytes in length. (which is 28 digits maximum)

**The question**
What is the right way to do this?
I prefer to avoid using strings for this. Using numeric values directly should be more efficient.

As I have mentioned in the beginning, this is for an existing solution, so all other data types and so on are working. Using SQLT_FLT for binding does work but the result is not satisfying.
It is a running solution. This means the code is working for other types as well.